# OnTriggerEnter : is it called in both collider object?

Tags: unity, collision-detection

I've 2 object: a Player and a Bonus object.

In both script I've "OnTriggerEnter" script.

In Player OnTrigger I: 
  Take Bonus value and add it to my Player (health, point, ammo)

In Bonus OnTrigger I: 
  Play audio (when take it), Play Particle System and so on...

But, it seems it's called only Player's OnTriggerEnter ... Why ?

In Unity, if I have OnCollision/OnTrigger enter in both object, which event is called ? Both ?

Thanks

Comment: please post the settings of each collider and rigidbody for your test

Comment: Please check if both colliders have "IS TRIGGER" flag checked.

Comment: Is there a rigidbody, is it the only rigidbody in that hierarchy?

Comment: Its been a long time but as far as I remember `OnCollisionEnter` or `OnTriggerEnter` will be executed when `Rigidbody` is attached to that object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to fire `onTrigger`, you need to have colliders in both game objects with at least one of them with a `rigidbody` and with at least one of them with `isTrigger` set to `true`.

When that's the case, the `OnTriggerEnter` is called on all game objects involved if you have the `OnTriggerEnter()` function written in the scripts attached to them.

It doesn't matter which one has the `rigidbody`, or which one has `isTrigger` set to `true`. You can mix and match the settings in any way you want.

You can also have both object with `isTrigger` set to `true`. If you are having issues, you may have misspelled the function call on the bonus object.